# Legend showing undefined in angular chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I'm using **angular-chart.js** to draw charts in my application. But i am facing a problem. Chart legend is showing **undefined** instead of labels.

My **js** code:

```
        $scope.labels_std = ['Total Students', 'Submitted fee', 'Has to submit'];
        $scope.options = {legend: {display: true, position: 'bottom'}};
        $scope.colors = ['#4D5360', '#949FB1', '#97BBCD'];
        $scope.data_std = [
                    $scope.allCount.students, 
                    $scope.allCount.fees, 
                    $scope.allCount.students - $scope.allCount.fees
                ];
```

**Markup is**:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-labels="labels_std" chart-data="data_std" chart-colors="colors" chart-options="options"></canvas>
```

But the **result** is this:

[image]

Comment: can you add working example where problem is. Also where is `$scope.series` in existing code

Comment: I added the series but that didn't work

Comment: see http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ but add some plunker so that it is easier to debug

Comment: i think you are missing `chart-series="series"` in html mark up and add `$scope.series`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's showing `undefined` because you haven't defined the `label` property for your datasets.

You need to set `label` property inside the `$scope.datasetOverride` model for each of your datasets. also, add the directive for it in your view markup.

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['chart.js']);

app.controller("BarCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.labels = ['Total Students', 'Submitted fee', 'Has to submit'];
   $scope.colors = ['#4D5360', '#949FB1', '#97BBCD'];
   $scope.std = 65, $scope.fee = 59, $scope.nfee = 80;
   $scope.data = [
      [$scope.std, $scope.fee, $scope.nfee],
      [$scope.std, $scope.fee, $scope.nfee],
      [$scope.std, $scope.fee, $scope.nfee]
   ];
   $scope.options = {
      legend: {
         display: true
      }
   }
   $scope.datasetOverride = [{
      label: 'My First Dataset'
   }, {
      label: 'My Second Dataset'
   }, {
      label: 'My Third Dataset'
   }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
   <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-colors="colors" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: But in pie chart, it's working fine even i didn't add "datasetOverride"

Comment: its because pie chart doesn't use `label` property for showing `legend`s. it shows legend for each *label* in labels array.

Comment: I've tried your way but it didn't solve my problem .. showing undefined

Comment: how you set it? add the directive?

Comment: <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-labels="labels" chart-data="data" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" data-series="series"></canvas>

Comment: If i enter some numbers in data like [50, 30, 20], it's working fine but when i enter some variables like [$scope.std, $scope.fee, $scope.nfee], it's showing undefined

Comment: no, it shows correctly. check edited example. maybe you have some other issues. *(which has nothing to do with this)* as you can clearly see on the given snippet it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it through a function i once found on internet looking for a ellipsis on legend labels.

You just have to call the function from your options->legend object

```
$scope.labels_std = ['Total Students', 'Submitted fee', 'Has to submit'];
$scope.options = {legend: {
    display: true, 
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
        generateLabels: function(chart){
            var dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
            var arcOpts = chart.options.elements.arc;

            //iterate the labels to return legend item interface 
            return chart.data.labels.map(function(label, i) {
                return {
                    text: label,
                    //lines below to emulate the default legend behaviour
                    fillStyle: Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(dataset.backgroundColor, i , arcOpts.backgroundColor),
                    strokeStyle: Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(dataset.borderColor, i , arcOpts.borderColor),
                    lineWidth: Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(dataset.borderWidth, i , arcOpts.borderWidth),
                    hidden: isNaN(dataset.data[i]) || chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[i].hidden,
                    index: i
                };
            });
        }
    }
}};

$scope.colors = ['#4D5360', '#949FB1', '#97BBCD'];

$scope.data_std = [
    $scope.allCount.students, 
    $scope.allCount.fees, 
    $scope.allCount.students - $scope.allCount.fees
];
```